# MongoDB array field $in array counting the number of matches

Tags: mongodb

For example I have docs:

`{field: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']}`

end request query:

`collection.find({field: {$in: ['x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b']})`

Can I get `...match_count: 2...` in result doc?
And set the min count matched for result docs?

Comment: can you show how should output look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[$setIntersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/#exp._S_setIntersection)** and **[$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/)** aggregations to return an array of elements that appear in both array inputs, and then get the length of the intersection.

The aggregation would look something like this:

```
[
  {
    '$project': {
      'match_count': {
        '$size': {
          '$setIntersection': ['$field', ['a', 'b']]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

`$setIntersection` is returning the intersection of the arrays `$field` (referencing the 'field' field within the document), and the array `['a', 'b']` (your input to check against). `$size` is then calculating the length of the intersection, and projecting that into the `match_count` field.